# Is there a term for logical foreign keys that aren't defined as foreign keys in the database?

Tags: database, terminology

One of my team's big tasks this year is to overhaul and normalize our legacy database structure. Many columns used by the application as foreign keys don't actually have a foreign key relationship defined in the database, and we are in the process of fixing that.

I'm wondering if there is a nice, succinct way of describing such a situation where there's a column that's clearly supposed to be a FK but is not defined in the database. I've been using "unofficial foreign key" or "loose foreign key" but usually those terms aren't clear enough and I have to explain what I mean (which is of course doable but takes a little time).

I haven't found any answers on Google, most results just describe why defining a FK is better. I'm also relatively new to DB design so perhaps I'm just thinking about this the wrong way.

Is there such a term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Fake" might get the point across more clearly, or, since foreign keys are a type of constraint, calling it "unenforced" would be more idiomatic.

Comment: Good ideas. I like "unenforced" a lot. Thanks!